# permutation matrix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Is it possible to decompose a `matrix A` having `n` rows and `n` columns to sum of `m [n x n]` permutation matrices. where m is the number of 1's in each row and each column in `matrix A`?

**UPDATE:**

yes, this is possible. I came across such an exmaple which is shown below - but How can we generalize the answer?

[image]

Comment: Assume first row of your decomposition matrices, their sum is not equal to A's first row, what do you mean exactly? and what is m? number of 1's in all row and columns are same?

Comment: Your sample decomposition contains a few errors: the (1,4) element in the first, and the (2,4) element in the second permutation matrix should be zero.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a [1-factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization). One algorithm is repeatedly to find a perfect matching and remove it; probably there are others.

Answer (score 0):

For the first permutation matrix, take the first 1 in the first row. For the second row, take the first 1 that is in a column you don't already have. For the third row, take the first 1 that is in a column you don't already have. And so on. Do this for all rows.

You now have one permutation matrix.

Next subtract your first permutation matrix from the original. This new matrix now has `m-1` ones in each row and column. So repeat the process `m-1` more times, and you'll have your `m` permutation matrices.

You can skip the last step, because a matrix with one 1 in each row and column already is a permutation matrix. There's no need to do any calculations.

This is a greedy algorithm that doesn't always work. We can make it work by changing the selection rule slightly. See below:

For your example:

```
    1 0 1 1
A = 1 1 0 1
    1 1 1 0
    0 1 1 1
```

In the first step, we pick (1,1) for the first row, (2,2) for the second row, (3,3) for the thrid row and (4,4) for the 4th row. We then have:

```
    1 0 0 0   0 0 1 1
A = 0 1 0 0 + 1 0 0 1
    0 0 1 0   1 1 0 0
    0 0 0 1   0 1 1 0
```

The first matrix is a permutation matrix. The second matrix has exactly two 1's in each row and column. So we pick, in order: (1,3), (2,1), (3,2) and... we're in trouble: the rows that contain a 1 in column 4 have already been used.

So how do we fix this? Well, we can keep track of the number of 1's remaining in each column. Instead of picking the first column that is unused, we pick the column with the lowest number of 1's remaining. For the second matrix above:

```
    0 0 1 1     0 0 X 0     0 0 X 0     0 0 X 0
B = 1 0 0 1 --> 1 0 0 1 --> 0 0 0 X --> 0 0 0 X
    1 1 0 0     1 1 0 0     1 1 0 0     X 0 0 0
    0 1 1 0     0 1 1 0     0 1 1 0     0 1 1 0
    -------     -------     -------     -------
    2 2 2 2     2 2 X 1     1 2 X X     X 1 X X
```

So we would pick column 4 in the second step, column 1 in the 3rd step, and column 2 in the 4th step.

There can always be only one column with one remaining 1. The other 1's must have been taken away in `m-1` previous rows. If you had two such columns, one of them would have had to have been picked as the minimum column before.

Comment: This wouldn't work (if I understand your algorithm correctly) for all matrices. Consider the matrix, A in question. Try running the second iteration on the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using a recursive (backtracking OR depth-first traversal) algorithm. Here is the **pseudo-code** for its solution:

```
void printPermutationMatrices(const int OrigMat[][], int permutMat[], int curRow, const int n){
//curPermutMatrix is 1-D array where value of ith element contains the value of column where 1 is placed in ith row
    if(curRow == n){//Base case
        //do stuff with permutMat[]
        printPermutMat(permutMat);
        return;
    }

    for(int col=0; col<n; col++){//try to place 1 in cur_row in each col if possible and go further to next row in recursion
        if(origM[cur_row][col] == 1){
            permutMat[cur_row] = col;//choose this col for cur_row
            if there is no conflict to place a 1 in [cur_row, col] in permutMat[]
                perform(origM, curPermutMat, curRow+1, n);
    }

    }
}
```

Here is how to call from your main function:

```
int[] permutMat = new int[n];
printPermutationMatrices(originalMatrix, permutMat, 0, n);
```