# how to shuffle a matrix

Tags: c, function, recursion

I have a matrix described as below:

> ```
> 1 0 0 0 0
> 1 1 0 0 0
> 1 1 1 0 0
> 1 1 1 0 0
> 1 0 1 1 1
> ```

I want to shuffle it into all the possible combinations, can anybody suggest a method for shuffling the matrix without changing its internal numbers.  In my matrix I have 13 ones, the rest zeros and when I shuffle, I want to have these 13 ones in all possible combinations.

Comment: Please be more specific on your use of the term "shuffle".

Comment: I mean these 13 one which I have in the matrix permute in all possible positions in the matrix.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP says "can anybody tell me the code" and SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [permutation matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020341/permutation-matrix)

Comment: Hint: There are 25! (25 * 24 * 23 * ... *1) combinations.  Pick one of the elements as the first element in a new matrix.  Then pick the 2nd element from one of the remaining 24, ...

Comment: @SouravGhosh sorry I did not know that it is against policy of the site. I will change it

Comment: @zenyang Thank you. Also, you may want to  take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here.

Comment: @chux: No, there are only (25!)/(25-13)!/13! = 5,200,300 combinations (binomial coefficient 25 over 13, or 25 choose 13), because the order of the elements does not matter.

Comment: @Nominal Animal Yes - of course: 5,200,300 unique combinations

Answer (score 3):

I won't give you the code (because then your grade would be mine, right?) but here's an idea:

- You have 25 values that can be either 0 or 1.
- Loop from 0 to 2^25 - 1.
- For each value, count the "1" bits.
- If the count is 13, turn value into a matrix.
- Now start optimizing. Maybe a recursive solution could give you results quicker.

Comment: There are 25! / ((25-13)! 13!) = 5,200,300 solutions among the 2**25 = 33,554,432 candidates, so about 15.5% of the candidates are valid solutions. If you use GCC and the `__builtin_popcount()` function, finding the solutions takes a fraction of a second on a typical machine. Just printing all those matrixes takes at least a couple of orders of magnitude longer, especially using `printf()`. Using `fwrite()` and a char buffer for the matrix, all matrices are found and printed in less than half a second on my HP Elitebook 820 laptop. The thing best to optimize is often surprising!

Comment: no I don't want to print them, I only need one of these permutation, it means that I will permute the matrix and each time I will check my constraints, if ok, it should stop, if not it will continue permuting. 
so you think that it is doable?

Comment: @zenyang Sure. The loop gives you all permutations eventually. Each time you have a number with 13 "1" bits, do your constraint checking.

Comment: thanks for your rapid reply, now the problem is that the function which I want to write to do the permutations, will print them all, and I have no chance to use each one of them. how could I permute, check, continue and so on?

Comment: @zenyang In pseudocode: `for (i = 0...2**25-1) { if (i has exactly 13 "1" bits) { check_constraints(); if (enough) { exit }  } }` will check them one by one until you want no more.

Comment: @NominalAnimal You raise a good point! Sometimes the total time you can gain by optimizing (milliseconds) is offset by the time to devise the optimized code (hours). You'll never get a return on your investment :-)